# Multiple Select box from2 Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

How can i create a Multiple select box from 2 arrays
1st array contains all values and the second array contains the values that will be marked as selected in multiple select

```
$a=array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
$b=array[3,7,8];
```

the multiple selectbox will have all the values from array `$a` but values from array `$b` will be selected.
Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: A `foreach` loop with an `in_array` call should give the result you desire

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$b=array(3,7,8);
$selected="";
foreach($a as $val)
{
    if(in_array($val,$b))
    {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    }

    //Code for create multi select drop down and echo $selected in option like

    <option $selected value="" ></option>
}
```

Comment: not working its selecting all the values after first match ie  3

Comment: Replace the whole `if` structure with `$selected=(in_array($val,$b) ? 'selected="selected"' : '');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$b=array(3,7,8);
$html = '<select multiple>';
foreach($a as $val)
{
    $selected = (in_array($val,$b)) ? 'selected' : '';
    $html .= '<option value="' . $a . '"' . $selected . '>' . $a . '</option>';
}
$html .= '</select>';
echo $html;
```